# COULD vs. COULD HAVE when talking about the past

Tags: could

I have long had difficulty distinguishing between COULD and COULD HAVE. I have two specific examples that I'm not exactly sure of. Could you enlighten me?

> 1. She needed money so much, she could even have worked in a KFC restaurant
> 2. Jim could’ve ordered fish in the diner yesterday, but he settled for venison

First question - are both of these correct? I would assume they are, but I'm really not sure. How about their COULD'VE counterparts:

> 1a. She needed money so much, she could even work in a KFC restaurant
>
> 2a. Jim could order fish in the diner yesterday, but he settled for venison

In my opinion both of them sound unnatural, but I can't say why.

Comment: "could" usually refers to ability, "could have" refers to making a choice, see the linked question for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**Could**" is about a hypothetical, or an option. It exists in the present.

"**Could have**" or "**could've**" is a hypothetical or option that only exists in the past.

1. She needed money so much, she could even have worked in a KFC restaurant

She needed money so badly that she **could** even **have** worked at KFC.

For clarity I made it "badly" so it doesn't sound like she needed "so much money," and I specified how that the first part of the sentence was connected to the second by using "that." I say "at KFC" rather than "a KFC restaurant" because unless someone is talking about a particular KFC, I don't hear them saying "a KFC," it's always just "KFC" and never with the word "restaurant" at the end.

The thing about sentence 1 that is slightly off as regards "**could**" is that it sounds almost like she had an opportunity, rather than that she would have liked an opportunity but didn't have one. 
Consider: She needed the money so badly that she **would** have worked at a KFC. 
This implies she wasn't able, but would have.
Or: If she needed the money so much, she **could** have worked at KFC.
This implies that getting a job at KFC is easy, and if she wanted to she **could** have gotten a job there.

2. Jim **could’ve** ordered fish in the diner yesterday, but he settled for venison.

Sentence 2 is fine. It does make me wonder which diners you frequent that have both fish an venison on the menu. You must have fancy diners. [It is also possible that like most people you sometimes write diner (a restaurant) when you mean dinner (a meal).]

1a. She needed money so much, she **could** even work in a KFC restaurant.

1a is wrong. The first part is in the past tense, the second part, by the use of **could** *without* **have** is in present tense. Sentence 1 is the more correct version.

2a. Jim **could** order fish in the diner yesterday, but he settled for venison.

2a is wrong. 
Jim **could** order fish at the diner. [present]

OR

Jim **could have** ordered fish at the diner yesterday. [past]

Jim's choice cannot exist both in the present and in the past, unless the option continues, as in the following: Jim **could have** fixed the garage door yesterday, but he didn't. He **could** still fix it today and have it done before the party this evening.